# Extracting name-value key pairs from a character array

Tags: arrays, matlab, character

I have name-value pairs in a character array:

```
a = '{A=true, up=false, left=false, B=false, select=false, right=false, down=false, start=false}'
```

Note that the accolades `{` are all included in array, and size is 1x92.

How can I extract all key value pairs into separate accessible values?

Comment: I rolled back your edit, as on Stack Overflow the question is supposed to contain just that, a question. If you want to add your own answer, please feel free to do so. If that's only adding timing, you might want to tick the "community wiki" checkbox though, as you're not adding extra information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more compact solution, no loop required:

```
s = regexp(a,'[{=, }]','split');
s(strcmp(s,{''})) = [];
name_val = [s(1:2:end) ; s(2:2:end)].'

name_val =

8×2 cell array

{'A'     }    {'true' }
{'up'    }    {'false'}
{'left'  }    {'false'}
{'B'     }    {'false'}
{'select'}    {'false'}
{'right' }    {'false'}
{'down'  }    {'false'}
{'start' }    {'false'}
```

Comment: Thanks, regular expression was on my mind too. Any comment on the efficiency of using regexp over loop?

Comment: @Kulbhushan No idea, you can try out both solutions with `timeit` and compare

Answer (score 3):

[`strsplit()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) using a custom delimiter is your friend:

```
a = '{A=true, up=false, left=false, B=false, select=false, right=false, down=false, start=false}';
% Get rid of leading and trailing characters, split on pairs
tmp = strsplit(a(2:end-1),',');
name_val = cell(numel(tmp,2));  % store in 2 column cell
for ii = 1:numel(tmp)
    tmp2 = strsplit(tmp{ii}, '=');  % Split name-value pair on =
    name_val{ii,1} = strtrim(tmp2{1});  % name
    name_val{ii,2} = strtrim(tmp2{2});  % value
end

name_val =

  8×2 cell array

    {'A'     }    {'true' }
    {'up'    }    {'false'}
    {'left'  }    {'false'}
    {'B'     }    {'false'}
    {'select'}    {'false'}
    {'right' }    {'false'}
    {'down'  }    {'false'}
    {'start' }    {'false'}
```

This will make you end up with a cell array of `n` rows, as many as you have key-value pairs, and 2 columns: key in the first, value in the second. I opted for a cell, rather than a struct, since your key names have different length, and cells allow for flexibility in the second column if you mix logical, numeric, and what have you not as keys.

I used [`strtrim()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html) to get rid of any leading/trailing white space.